# How to know which tests were run together in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, automated-tests

**My question in general is this:** when I run automated tests in parallel how can I know which of them were run at the same time?

**My issue is this:** I'm running tests in parallel (4 tests per time) but I have no idea which of them are executing together (at the same time) and which are waiting.

After my tests are executed there are some failures and it could be that the cause of the failures is other tests that were executing in the same time with the failed test. So I want to know which tests were executing together so I can run them together again to debug the failed test.

**Technologies I use: NUnit 3.0, C#, Selenium WebDriver, Jenkins**

I'm glad to hear any possible solution  (doesn't matter if it's hard to apply)

Comment: you can track start and end time for each test and compare them to find parallel execution cases.

Answer (score 0):

For debug purposes, you can run the NUnit console with the `--trace=Verbose` option.

This will write a log to the directory you are executing in, which will look a little like this:

```
14:56:13.972 Info  [13] TestWorker: Worker#4 executing TestsSuite1
14:56:13.973 Debug [13] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing TestA
14:56:13.976 Debug [12] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing TestB
14:56:13.976 Debug [16] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing TestC
14:56:13.980 Debug [12] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing TestD
14:56:13.982 Debug [16] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing TestE(False,False,False,0)
14:56:13.989 Debug [16] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing TestE(False,False,True,0)
```

I believe the numbers in the square brackets identify different threads, so here, you can see that workers 12 and 16 where running TestC and TestD simultaneously.

Of course, it's never as simple as just seeing which tests where running concurrently, but this may help narrow issues down.

Comment: Using --trace=Info will give you less output and be easier to interpret. Currently, NUnit doesn't run test methods in the same fixture in parallel, so you only need to look at lines like the Info line above.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to disable parallelism selectively until you find the combination that causes the problem.

1. Disable all parallelism by running with --workers=0. If the same tests fail, then you don't have a parallelism problem.
2. Selectively rerun the failed tests together, using the --test or --where option to select them.  Edit the fixtures to enable/disable parallelism until you hit the combination that does the job.